# SQLAlchemy onupdate is not working with session.merge()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i'm using `updated_at` in SQLAlchemy model class like,

```
updated_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False, default=now, onupdate=now)
```

and i updated a row of this class with `session.merge()`

```
row = SomeClass(**data)
session.merge(row)
session.flush()
```

then i see the logs, the `updated_at` is not updated to `now()`. it just updated only changed data in dict.

so i changed my code like this.

```
row = session.query(SomeClass).get(data['id'])
row.some_column = data['some_column']
session.flush()
```

then the `updated_at` column is updated!! what's the difference between `merge()` and direct assign?

Answer (score 0):

It's defined in the documentation that "With merge(), the given “source” instance is not modified nor is it associated with the target Session, and remains available to be merged with any number of other Session objects." [sqlalchemy merge documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#merging)

use `session.commit()` after `merge()`